# iframe that can't be modifyed by its parent document

Tags: html, iframe

In HTML5, there are iframe, which can contain an HTML document inside the parent document. There are several sanboxing options as this [W3C page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) shows it. As far as I understand it, it prevents the iframe scripts from accessing/modifying/interfering with the parent DOM. That is a parent protection against its child.

Now, in HTML5, is there a parameter of the iframe (or it could be another tag) that prevent the parent page to access to the iframe content? Meaning, a child protection against its parent? And of course, if it is an iframe attribute, that would need to be an attribute that can't be removed through a javascript call such as ".removeAttribute()".

Comment: `document.querySelector('iframe').src="blank:about"`

Comment: Yes, sure, you would still be able to erase its content. Or delete it. But I am mostly thinking about alteration and access of its content. As far as I can see, the protection only apply when it is from another domain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: I can't think of a situation where a site needs protection from...itself?